# How to turn a statement in a string to actual statement without using eval?

Tags: javascript

```
var statement = "true && 'yes' || 'no'"
eval(statement)
```

gives me 'yes'.

But I need a way to do that without using eval. Is there anyway to do so?

Comment: This statement will always evaluate to `"yes"`. Why do you need that?

Comment: Yes. I need a way that does the same without using eval.

Comment: Already var statement contains "yes" so you got it .. put alert(statement) to check it

Comment: @Luaox The stupidest way: `statement.split(" && ").pop().split(" || ").shift()`.

Comment: If I didn't use eval, the variable statement will just be a normal string. I want to turn that string to a statement without using eval.

Comment: You want to *eval*uate a statement. That's what the `eval` function is for. If you need to use, use it. But chances are there is a better approach to whatever you're trying to achieve. Assuming that statement is completely open to change (so you can't do something like VisioNs suggestion), your only other real option is to dynamically insert a new `<script>` element into the page.

Comment: So I only have one option to do that without using eval? Any other options?

Comment: @Luaox - Why can you not use `eval` here? Where does the statement you need to evaluate come from?

Comment: I heard that eval is 'evil' so I had feelings not to use it at all. I don't even know why its 'evil'. And I'm running the script in google chrome extension.

Answer (score 1):

As [@James Allardice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518100/how-to-turn-a-statement-in-a-string-to-actual-statement-without-using-eval#comment21978092_15518100) stated in the comments, if you need to use `eval`, just use it.

If for some reason you don't like `eval` as a typical JavaScript function, there is another workaround which does basically the same:

```
var statement = "true && 'yes' || 'no'";
new Function("return " + statement)();
```

Comment: The other option I mentioned in my comment (creating a new `<script>` element and appending it to the DOM) may be preferred (in a browser context only of course) since it doesn't involve `eval` in any way. The `Function` constructor is effectively an alias for `eval` and whatever reason for not using `eval` there is, it should probably apply to `Function` too.

Comment: @JamesAllardice But will the appended `<script>` tag contents be cross browserly evaluated? In jQuery for `loadScript` they use global eval.

Comment: @VisioN - As far as I'm aware it will be. I can't say that for certain though. You're right about jQuery though, so perhaps there are issues with it. Obviously the main downside is that it only works in the browser. You can't use that technique in an environment like Node.

Comment: @Luaox There is *no* other "better" *universal* solution than provided here, so you can simply accept this answer `:)`.